# PInvoke - Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

This is the header file signature and C code I am trying to use in C#:

```
__declspec(dllexport) emxArray_real_T *emxCreateWrapper_real_T(real_T *data, int32_T rows, int32_T cols);

struct emxArray_real_T
{
    real_T *data;
    int32_T *size;
    int32_T allocatedSize;
    int32_T numDimensions;
    boolean_T canFreeData;
};

emxArray_real_T *emxCreateWrapper_real_T(real_T *data, int32_T rows, int32_T
  cols)
{
  emxArray_real_T *emx;
  int32_T size[2];
  int32_T numEl;
  int32_T i;
  size[0] = rows;
  size[1] = cols;
  emxInit_real_T(&emx, 2);
  numEl = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    numEl *= size[i];
    emx->size[i] = size[i];
  }

  emx->data = data;
  emx->numDimensions = 2;
  emx->allocatedSize = numEl;
  emx->canFreeData = FALSE;
  return emx;
}
```

I am currently trying to invoke it as follows in C#:

```
[DllImport(@"C:\bla\bla.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern emxArray_real_T emxCreateWrapper_real_T(double[,] data, int rows, int cols);

double[,] array2D = new double[,] { { 1 }, { 3 }, { 5 }, { 7 } };
var x = emxCreateWrapper_real_T(array2D, 1, 4);
```

but get:

```
Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible.
```

`emxArray_real_T` currently looks like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct emxArray_real_T
{
    //public IntPtr data;
    //public IntPtr size;
    double[] data;
    int[] size;
    public int allocatedSize;
    public int numDimensions;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool canFreeData;
}
```

Comment: What's `emxArray_real_T`? The problem probably lies in that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems. First of all your C++ function returns a pointer (emxArray_real_T *) but your import declaration returns a struct. That cannot work. Also, you declare data as double[,] in the import declaration, but as double[] in the structure. Suggestions:

- Replace the struct by a class
- Determine if data should be a double[] or a double[,]
- Also check the final size of real_T. I believe it's a platform dependent variable that could be float (32 bit) or double (64 bit).

Comment: I have done what you suggested but get: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. Btw, typedef double real_T - I have used C# double without problems in the past for real_T ...

Comment: Yes, so you've past the first step. Now you have other problems. I believe you have another question pending here on SO about correctly marshaling this emxArray_real_T. Have you done what's suggested? Please paste the full C++ struct definition if you need more help.

Comment: will write another question. Thanks!